# asp.net event handler for dynamicallycreated button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, dynamic, event-handling

I have a button created in code behind like so:

```
some method {
    Button btnExportToExcel = new Button();
    btnExportToExcel.Text = "Export To Excel";
    btnExportToExcel.Click += new EventHandler(btnExportToExcel_Click);
    pnlListView.Controls.Add(btnExportToExcel);
}

protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

The problem is that I can't ever get to execute the code from the event method.

Why is that?

Comment: When is Somethod called? Dinamic controls should be added in PreInit event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you adding controls to page in preinit event handler? [Check](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: It is loaded in the Page_Load method and inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` statament

Comment: Ok loading it in Pre_Init fixes the issue. Thank you.

Comment: There is another small issue, what if I want to add the button control after other controls which get conditionally created? Meaning they might exist at pre_init

Answer (score 1):

You must add the button to any controler .

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnExportToExcel = new Button();
        btnExportToExcel.Text = "Export To Excel";
        btnExportToExcel.Click += new EventHandler(btnExportToExcel_Click);
        //this is add the button to the form1
        this.form1.Controls.Add(btnExportToExcel);
    }

    void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //...
        Response.Write("click me...");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I am adding it to a panel. Edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the dynamic controls in the Page's Init event handler so that the ViewState and Events are triggered appropriately.